# Getting a SpannableString to my implementation InfoWindowAdapter

Tags: android, google-maps

Google Maps V2.  I have markers on a map that I have an associated SpannableString associated with.  I want to display this spannableString in the popup window when the marker is clicked.  I create an implementation of InfoWindowAdapter, but then I realize that all the data it receives is from MarkerOptions.. I can't attach a SpannableString to MarkerOptions.title() or MarkerOptions.snippit() because they only accept String.  I can't extend MarkerOptions because it's final.

It appears I am sol.. however, there must be someway to do this I think.  Is there a way to arbitrarily associated data with an object?  I guess I could create a HashMap.. Seems hacky and obtuse..

All help appreciated. thank youuuu!

Answer (score 0):

Using `Map` is the most often used workaround. See the discussion on [gmaps-api-issues](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4650).

Alternatively you may try [Android Maps Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/), which adds `Marker.setData(Object)` and `Object Marker.getData()`.